Error: EmailException (Java): Sending the email to the following server failed
I am using commons-email 1.6.0 to send emails and I have been encountering a weird issue where the emails are only sent successfully when the application is launched from netbeans or using java 18.0.2. If I use a different java version I am getting this error. I can't figure out why it only works using java 18.0.2, does anyone have an idea?
    public boolean sendMailHTML(String subject, String msgBody, String[] destinataires, String[] copies, String[] blindCopies) {

        boolean result = false;
        try {
            HtmlEmail email = new HtmlEmail();

            email.setHostName(Config.getHostName());
            email.setSmtpPort(Config.getSmtpPort());

            if (Config.isSslEnabled()) {
                email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
                email.setSslSmtpPort(String.valueOf(Config.getSmtpPort()));
            }

            if (Config.isTlsEnabled()) {
                email.setStartTLSEnabled(true);
                email.setStartTLSRequired(true);
            }

            if (Config.isDebugEnabled()) {
                email.setDebug(true);
                BaseLoggerNotifier.logInfo(ILogger.levelErreur.debug, "Mail Configuration Loaded: \n" + Config.toString());
            }

            String login = Config.getLogin();
            String password = Config.getPassword();
            if (login != null && !login.equals("")) {
                email.setAuthentication(login, password);
            }
            email.setFrom(Config.getFrom());
            for (String dest : destinataires) {
                if (!dest.equals("")) {
                    email.addTo(dest);
                }
            }
            if (copies != null) {
                for (String copie : copies) {
                    if (!copie.equals("")) {
                        email.addCc(copie);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (blindCopies != null) {
                for (String bCopie : blindCopies) {
                    if (!bCopie.equals("")) {
                        email.addBcc(bCopie);
                    }
                }
            }
            email.setSubject(subject);
            if (msgBody != null && !msgBody.equals("")) {
                email.setHtmlMsg(msgBody);
            } else {
                email.setHtmlMsg("<HTML></HTML>");
            }
        
            email.send();

            result = true;
        } catch (EmailException ex) {
            BaseLoggerNotifier.logInfo(ILogger.levelErreur.erreur, getClass().getName(), ex, "sendMailHTML()");
        }
        return result;
    }


    DEBUG: Jakarta Mail version 1.6.7
    DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
    DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
    DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle]}
    DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle], smtp=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle], pop3=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store,Oracle], imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle], smtps=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Oracle], pop3s=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,pop3s,com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3SSLStore,Oracle]}
    DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
    DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
    DEBUG SMTP: need username and password for authentication
    DEBUG SMTP: protocolConnect returning false, host=####, user=####, password=
    DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
        DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "#####", port 465, isSSL false
        2024-06-07 10:43:25,975 INFO  [exceptions] mailtransfert.MailSender -> (org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException) Sending the email to the following server failed : ######:465 -> sendMailHTML()
            2024-06-07 10:43:25,975 INFO  [exceptions] org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1298)
            2024-06-07 10:43:25,975 INFO  [exceptions] org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1282)
            2024-06-07 10:43:25,975 INFO  [exceptions] mailtransfert.MailSender.sendMailHTML(MailSender.java:110)
            2024-06-07 10:43:25,976 INFO  [exceptions] calcul.Calcul_Alarmes.sendMailOuverture(Calcul_Alarmes.java:412)
            2024-06-07 10:43:25,976 INFO  [exceptions] calcul.Calcul_Alarmes.runAction(Calcul_Alarmes.java:367)
            2024-06-07 10:43:25,976 INFO  [exceptions] framework.prototypes.ICalcul.run(ICalcul.java:142)
            2024-06-07 10:43:25,976 INFO  [exceptions] java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

After launching with -Djavax.net.debug=all
I can see the exception:
***
calcul.Calcul_Alarmes, handling exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
%% Invalidated:  [Session-12, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
calcul.Calcul_Alarmes, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = internal_error
calcul.Calcul_Alarmes, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 50                               ......P
calcul.Calcul_Alarmes, called closeSocket()
2024-06-07 11:42:22,388 ERROR [general] mailtransfert.MailSender -> (org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException) Sending the email to the following server failed : #### -> sendMailHTML()


Looks to me like mailtransfert.MailSender is not providing you will enough info. Please post the code of sendMailHTML

if it's a source issue why does it work on java 18.0.2

post the Java stack trace to the question. could be issue of unsupported TLS cypher.

added all the logs

You should have added the log output separately. I fixed that. You seem to be using a non-standard logging API. What is that? Running both your 'good version' and bad version with -Djavax.net.debug=all might be instructive. For the record, I was not saying it was a "source issue". I was simply wondering why you seem to have less than informative trace output

Added the exception in the post

I was able to fix by adding these two jvm properties, it seems that the jdk 18.0.2 had the necessary truststore which is why it was working. After adding these two properties it worked.
javax.net.ssl.trustStore=NUL
javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT

This answer is really helpful Import Windows certificates to Java
